# How would I make this query work for memcached?

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

First off, I want to add memcached to be used in ps_pagination http://phpsense.com/2007/php-pagination-script/

There are two queries I need to make use memecached. I got the first one fine. The other one does this:

```
$rs = @mysql_query($this->sql . " LIMIT {$this->offset}, {$this->rows_per_page}" );
```

Where `{$this->offset}` and `{$this->rows_per_page}` you can just think of as numbers, of course.

So I want to do something like

```
$rs = $this->memcache->get($this->key)
```

from {$this->offset} to {$this->rows_per_page} ;

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: not ever use @ to suppress errors.

Comment: @Dagon this is in a script I got online that worked so I didn't want to mess with it until now that I wanted to add memcached. I can remove them since I guess it is generally bad to suppress errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hash of the query and store this as the key, this is what I typically do.

So if I find something in memcache I return the result, if not I run the query and save it into memcache

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that the other query I took care of is the same as the one I need help with except it was just a plain `mysql_query($sql)` That will take care of it being in cache. What I just don't know is how I could only grab the items from the resulting array that are from  {$this->offset} to {$this->rows_per_page} EDIT - Talking through this made me think I have an idea of what I need to do. I'll answer back after I look into it.